# mysql_query doesn't show all query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show all distinct id_did in cc_did_use

```
function getdidbycc($cccard_from_sipcard){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id_did from cc_did_use where id_cc_card='$cccard_from_sipcard'");
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
    $text = $row['id_did'];
    }
    return $text;
}
```

I have two `id_cc_card="31"` and one that value has `id_dd="14"` and another `one = "13"` 
but result just show first one.

How I can show both of them?

and after that I have another function

```
function get_did ($p){

$result = mysql_query("SELECT did FROM cc_did WHERE id ='$p'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
 echo $row['id_did'].'<br/>';
}
}
```

when I run getdidbycc function , it returns two value , 13 and 14 , 
How I can get did numbers from this two values?

Comment: Your first mistake is using MySql, as it has been deprecated. Rather use mySqli. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: @DylandeStPern or `PDO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching result and checking in an `if` condition which will execute only once.

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $text = $row['id_did'];
}
```

You have to fetch the result until there is value in the resultant array. So try with `while` loop like,

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))   // while there are records
 {
    $text[] = $row['id_did'];    // store the result in array $text
 } 
 return $text;    // return the array
```

Comment: he is returning the value instead printing

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to use `mysqli` or `pdo` instead of `mysql` otherwise you will face issues in updated version of php

As per your code $text value is gets over write due to loop so use an array something like this

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $text[] = $row['id_did'];
  }

return $text;
```

or you can just return complete data as `return $row;`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
    $text = $row['id_did'];
    }
```

**change the above line to this**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
    echo $row['id_did'].'<br/>';

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop like that : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Mysql fetch array returns the current element only

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $text[] = $row['id_did'];
}
return $text; // returns both
```